# Reading files from from the folder as the same order in which they appears

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have one folder. In that I have some files in the order, filename_100, filename_101, filename_200, filename_201. I have to read the files in the same order. I have used the below code. But I can't get the expected output. Randomly it is reading files from the folder.

Code:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(order_path):
   for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
```

Can someone suggest me better solution for this?

Comment: Files do not appear, they are in a folder. You can sort them on date, size, name etc., but all this will not be their order. Because there is no order!

Comment: @Alex.S: Files (including subdirectories) in a directory _do_ have a natural order, but in most file systems that ordering is not simple, and may change as a result of modifying the directory's contents; it may also be influenced by a hashing function used on the file names. FWIW, it's possible to determine the order of files in a FAT filesystem (eg on a USB full of MP3 files) simply by writing the files in the desired order into an empty directory, but that order may be disrupted if you later go back to a directory and change it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that files have any *order* in a directory. But if you want to sort them, just use `sorted(...)`:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(order_path):
    for f in sorted(files):
        print(os.path.join(subdir, f))
```

*Edited:* Better use `os.path.join(...)` to join the file to the path, it takes care of your os's separators, etc.

If you want to sort by any number following the last `_` in your filename, you can change the sorting-directive to something like:

```
sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.split('_')[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider sorting your filenames numerically as follows:

```
def get_number(filename):
    if filename.find('_') != -1:
        name, number = os.path.splitext(filename)[0].split('_')
        return (name, int(number))
    else:
        return filename

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(order_path):
    for file in sorted(files, key=get_number):
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
        print filepath
```

This would then cope with the following kind of naming:

```
filename_1.txt
filename_100.txt
filename_101.txt
filename_200.txt
filename2_1.txt
filename2_100.txt
filename2_101.txt
filename2_200.txt
```

The function spots any file containing an `_` and then converts the number into an integer, it returns a tuple holding the name so that differently named files are grouped together.

If you are more interested in just the numbers, i.e. each of the files has a different name, but you still want to keep the numerical order, then replace the following line in  the `get_number()` function:

```
return (int(number), name)
```

Comment: Yes. I want to sort the files in the ascending order of the number associated with that File name. Its Working fine for me. Thank you, @Martin Evans